# Overwrite a variable name from an imported module in Python?

Tags: python, module

I have a file a that is comprised of modules that I have written. I would like to pass a variable name that ovewrites the existing variable in each of these modules.

file a has variable x

files b, c, and d are imported into file. Each of these modules has a predetermined variable x.

I'd like to establish the value of variable x in file a and pass it through files b,c,d.

I attempted to do all of this in one file.

```
variable = "x"

import file b
fileb.x
```

However the original value of variable x is being run that was already in file b

Comment: How about "fileb.x = x" (executed in "filea")?

Comment: `x` in `b` will be used as predetermined when importing `b`.  You can see and change `b.x` after importing, but that won't affect calculations that already used it.  It's a good idea to write functions in `b` that use `x` as an argument.  Then you can do `b.foo(x)` using the value from the main.

Comment: So go into file b and establish that the file from a is carried through as an argument?